# getElementByID when ID is dynamically generated

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a Chrome bookmarklet to grab data off of a site for work. I do not have access to modify the code of the site.

This is an example of a field I'm trying to grab:

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:100%;" bindonce="" class="ng-scope">
    <de-field-label>
        <div class="pull-left ng-scope" style="width: 100%">
            <label class="pull-left">Last Name</label>
        </div>
    </de-field-label>

    <input class="tt-input ng-scope"
           bo-class="{'tt-agency-required': field.agencyValidation === 1}" 
           de-cascade=""
           ng-disabled="true"
           de-input-mask=""
           de-text-box=""
           sectionid="0b340920-8989-ce72-7bb4-08d51598a6d9-0" 
           id="Victims_0b340920-8989-ce72-7bb4-08d51598a6d9_0_lastName"
           disabled="disabled">
</div>
```

The id is dyamically generated

Comment: Please take the time to properly format the HTML in your question so that your question is more readable.

Comment: If `id` is different with each page load, then you have to use something like classes or `querySelector`.

Comment: So it's the `Victims_0b340920-8989-ce72-7bb4-08d51598a6d9_0_lastName` you are trying to select? Is the format `Victims_<someguid>_lastName`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the attribute selector to check if the id starts with something

```
document.querySelector('[id^=Victims_]')
```

or ends with something

```
document.querySelector('[id$=lastName]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know what the ID will be, `getElementById` is useless to you.

Find something else about the element that uniquely identifies it, such as a class, or a `data-*` attribute, or it's relationship in the DOM with an element that you do know the ID of. In short, anything you could express with a [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Then use that as an argument to [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Answer (score 0):

If I have not misunderstood the ID is always different so you have to use something else to identify the input and then go and read the ID
I will try with:

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("tt-input").item(0);
var id = input.id
```